# What is the solution to single-check chess?

Tags: chess-variants, check, study, solving

Single-check chess is a variant where the first person to give check wins. [There is a website](https://www.chessvariants.com/winning.dir/singleck.html) that claims it has been solved, with white winning in four moves; however, I cannot find the moves anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

If you trust Stockfish's evaluation on [lichess.org](https://lichess.org/analysis/threeCheck/rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR_w_KQkq_-_0_1_%2B2%2B2#0), using the "three check" variant where both sides already have two checks, White wins in 5 moves with 1. e4, 1. e3, 1. Nc3, or 1. Na3, and loses otherwise.

Comment: It's lichess.org - could you provide a link to the analysis board you used to discover this so that we too can explore further?

Answer (score 3):

```
[FEN ""]

1. Nc3 e6 (1...d5 2. Nb5 Kd7 3. Nf3) 2. Ne4 Ke7 3. d3 f6 (3... Nf6 4. Bg5) 4. Bg5 fxg5 5. Qd2 Nf6 6. Qxg5
```

And it's check next move. Very far from the quickest or the most elegant solution, but this will do until somebody posts a good one.